# getting more items in XML responce

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am using **as3** , **AIR** with

I am making a desktop App that will search Popular Art form deviantArt and show them in the window one by one.When the  **XML responce** is recieved it has always **(60 items)** only 
what to do for further results for the same request 
request is like below

http://backend.deviantart.com/rss.xml?type=deviation&q=boost%3Apopular+all+time%2FArt

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strict deviantART dependent. Check out the info page: https://www.deviantart.com/developers/rss

It's said that this is an RSS feed, which means that they may not provide option to offset and search for particular results. They just show you the last let's say 60 results, and they will constantly change when there is a new post.

As I see they are going with [Media RSS](http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss), which as I see does not have an offset property.

So shortly said - you cannot get previous posts, you just need to keep looking for the latest ones and maybe store them in your own database?